# Foreach loop declare variable on select table array

Tags: php, sql-server

Is it possible to create variable inside foreach loop that each variable name depend on column that I select?

Here is my code:

```
    //sql select string declaration
    $sql = "select [Rec_ID],[Bike_ID],[Station],['Line']
            from [rfttest].[dbo].[RFT_Records_Log]
            where [Rec_ID] = '{$_GET['recid']}'";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); //query
    //if query fail print out error
    if($query === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }
    //continue with fetch array
    $recdata = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    //foreach to declare variable
    foreach($recdata as $x => $a)
    {
        $"$x" = $"$a";
    }
```

In this code I should successfully declare variable like:

```
$Rec_ID , $Bike_ID , $Station , $Line
```

I still get a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: question seems to be unclear

Comment: u cant name variable dynamically so `$"$x" = $"$a";`   to  `$x=$a;` thats were the parse error is from

Comment: Do you just want the column names from the table?

Comment: @Mystro You can name dynamically in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php. But it seems this situation is different.

Comment: @Manwal Thanks , but i meant how it was being done in the current situation Thanks tho. Lesson learnt

Comment: @mdamia yes i mean that :(

Comment: [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) . `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,  COLUMN_DEFAULT   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE table_name = 'table_name';`

Comment: @mdamia thanks but i'm using sql server :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can do this:

```
foreach($recdata as $x => $a)
{
    $x = $a;
}
```

Use following query:

```
$sql = "select [Rec_ID],[Bike_ID],[Station],['Line']
        from [rfttest].[dbo].[RFT_Records_Log]
        where [Rec_ID] = '{".$_GET['recid']."}'";
```

or escape `'` with `\` like:

```
$sql = "select [Rec_ID],[Bike_ID],[Station],['Line']
    from [rfttest].[dbo].[RFT_Records_Log]
    where [Rec_ID] = \'{$_GET['recid']}\'";
```

Comment: You helped me once :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

try without quotes

```
$$x = $$a;
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I think an array is want you need.

```
  $data["$x"] = $a;
```